# Typescript: Extract<> not working as intended?

Tags: typescript, types

My question is: Is typescript's type checker making a mistake here, or am I? **I'm not looking for a workaround,** I already found one.

I want to build a class `Num` that takes a number string of that number as an argument, in a way that I get a type error if the string doesn't match the number. So, for example:

```js
const test1 = new Num("two", 2) // ok
const teset2 = new Num("two", 3) // type error
```

For that, I've built the following type class:

```js
type Numbers = {
    name: "two",
    type: 2
} | {
    name: "three",
    type: 3
}

class Num<T extends Numbers["type"]> {
    value: T
    typeName: Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>["name"]

    constructor(typeName: Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>["name"], value: T) {
        this.value = value;
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }
}
```

Given that the constructor argument `typeName` has exactly the same type as `this.typeName`, I expect the assignment

```js
this.typeName = typeName
```

to work without issue.

However, I get a type error on this line, saying:

```
Type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>["name"] | Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>["name"]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>["name"] & Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>["name"]'.
  Type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>["name"]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>["name"] & Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>["name"]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>["name"] & Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>["name"]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>["name"]'.
        Type '"two"' is not assignable to type '"three"'.
          Type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>["name"]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>["name"]'.
            Type 'Extract<{ name: "two"; type: 2; }, { type: T; }>' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>'.
              Type '{ type: T; } & { name: "two"; type: 2; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ name: "three"; type: 3; }, { type: T; }>'.
```

To reiterate: My question is if typescript's type checker making a mistake here, or if it's me. **I'm not looking for a workaround,** I already found one.

Comment: If you call `new Primitive("number", 2)` you get an error because `T` is inferred as `2` and not `number`.  If that's not your issue, please [edit] the code to fix it.

Comment: The type checker is being overly cautious because the key is a union type. If `k` is a union, then `obj[k]=v` can be unsafe because you might be assigning to the wrong property (e.g., `obj` is of type `{a: number, b: string}`, `k` is of type `"a"|"b"`, then `obj[k]=0` is an issue if `k` turns out to be `"b"`) This was addressed in [ms/TS#30769](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), which catches a lot of actual errors but unfortunately also prevents a lot of perfectly safe code like yours.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. `T` can either be `number`, `string`, or `number | string`. In all cases, the type of  `typeName` (the argument) should match the type of `this.typeName`, so it should check out. The issue you mentioned seems to be about "target side", meaning an actual object being indexed. Can you elaborate on how that applies here?

Comment: The compiler is only analyzing the types, and your types are indexed access types, which looks like indexing into an object.  If you write `y = x` but `y` and `x` are both of type `ObjType[Key1 | Key2]` then the compiler will be worried that there is an actual key of type `Key1 | Key2` and that it's not safe to do the assignment.  In your case that isn't possible, but the compiler can't see it (because it's only looking at the types here).  Does that make sense or is it still failing to connect? (Also, could you check my first comment and fix that issue when you get a chance?)

Comment: Re: First comment, not convinced that's an issue, but I modified the question regardless. Re: the other one, I'm still "failing to connect". If I do `new Num("two", 2)`, the expression type checks, so for `T = 2`, the expression `"num"` is compatible with type `Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>["name"]`, and the expression `2` is compatible with type `T`. Can you explain to me why `Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>["name"]` isn't compatible with `Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>["name"]` in this case, if "only looking at the types"? Concretely with examples, without just referencing some rules.

Comment: @jcalz Feel free to write an answer if you need more space.

Comment: Your code is safe but fails due to ms/TS#30769. Inside `Num`, `typeName` is of an *indexed access type* (IAT) of the form `U[K]` where `U` is `Extract<Numbers, {type: T}>` and `K` is `"name"`. It stays an IAT because `T` is generic (if it were specified, then it would be some subtype of `"two" | "three"`). IATs behave differently on each side of an assignment. *Any example I give for where this is useful will not use your code, since `K` would have to be a union.* This might be a bug/limitation in TS (and could be raised as such), but ms/TS#30769 is why, as shown by testing in TS3.3 vs TS3.5.

Comment: [Works in TS3.3](https://tsplay.dev/mpKzgN), [Fails in TS3.5](https://tsplay.dev/m3oKym).  Do you need a concrete example of where ms/TS#30769 actually *helps* something? I could put one in my answer if I write one.  Anyway, are we on the same page now?  Or at least close enough where it's worth our collective efforts to write and review a full answer? I don't want to waste time by collating doc links and writing examples if the chance that you will accept it is low.

Comment: Ooh I think I get it. For the type to check out in the _class_, it has to consider the cases where `T` is either `"two"`, `"three"` _and_ `"two" | "three"`. In the last case, due to the issue you posted, it will create an intersection of the types for `typeName`, which results in `never`, since there is no inersection. Would you agree? If so, go ahead & write an answer, I'll accept it. And if not, maybe also write an answer, it will bring clarity.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I’ll write an answer when I get to a real computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is safe; the error TypeScript is giving you is a false positive, due to the behavior of [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), where assignments to [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) which produce [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) while *reading* require [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) when *writing*.

This feature was [introduced in TypeScript 3.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types), and you can verify that your code works in TypeScript 3.4 and below, but fails in TypeScript 3.5 and above.  This feature does have some benefits, but the examples that show it will necessarily not involve your code.

---

The canonical issue looks like:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number
}
function f(o: Foo, k: keyof Foo, v: Foo[keyof Foo]) {
  o[k] = v; // accepted in TS3.4 and below, error in TS3.5 and above
}
f({ a: "abc", b: 123 }, "a", 2); // okay
```

The implementation of `f()` is unsafe, as evidenced by the call at the bottom which ends up saving a `number` to a property that should be `string`.  But before microsoft/TypeScript#30769 the compiler allowed it.  After all, the assignment is of the type `Foo[keyof Foo]` on both the left and right side of the assignment.  The problem is that reading from a property is not the same sort of type operation as writing to a property.  If I don't know if `k` is `"a"` or `"b"`, then the only save type for `v` would be something assignable to *both* `Foo["a"]` *and* `Foo["b"]`. That is, `string & number`, not `string | number`.  And since `string & number` is equivalent to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), it really means that it's not safe to assign anything at all to `o[k]` as written.

The introduction of this error is an improvement to type safety, but quite a detriment to developer productivity, since there are a lot of situations analogous to this that the compiler now complains about but which are either perfectly safe or technically unsafe but unlikely to be a problem in practice.  It is what it is, though.

---

Back to your code: the compiler sees `Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>["name"]` as an indexed access type where the object type is `Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>` and the key type is `"name"`.  Because `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the union `Numbers`, the compiler wants to account for the situation where it *is* a union, as in:

```
const test3 = new Num(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "two" : "three",
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? 2 : 3
); // okay
```

So the compiler as an indexed access type which wants to be a union when being read.  It then decides that it should be an *intersection* when being written, and that's why you get the error involving the intersection of the members of `Numbers` (which is an empty intersection equivalent to `never` also).

Again, though, this is a false positive.  While you probably didn't intend to allow the `test3` call above, the fact is that `this.typeName` and `typeName` are the same exact type, and allowing the assignment from the latter to the former is not, in and of itself, a type safety error.  It *would* be if you had a value `n` of type `Extract<Numbers, { type: T }>` and tried to assign `n.name = typeName`, but TypeScript doesn't actually complain about analogous operations of that sort:

```
function assign1<N extends Numbers>(n: N, typeName: N["name"]) {
  n.name = typeName; // no error
}
function assign2(n: Numbers, typeName: Numbers["name"]) {
  n.name = typeName; // no error
}
```

So, who knows?  TypeScript isn't fully type-safe or consistent and doesn't intend to be (see [a note on soundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) and [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals)).  I'd say that your particular run-in with microsoft/TypeScript#30769 is probably a bug or a design limitation of TypeScript, and if you want you could raise it as such.  I wouldn't expect much to come of that, as I imagine the TS team would think this particular approach with `Extract` is not the recommended way to write the code, and would ask to see a more conventional situation where the problem arises.

---

Okay, in conclusion:

Your code is safe and the compiler is making a mistake... unless you actually intended to disallow calls with unions, in which case maybe both you and the compiler are making a mistake, or, to be charitable to TypeScript, the compiler is obliquely warning you about that problem (but probably shouldn't).

In any case, the behavior in question is definitely caused by microsoft/TypeScript#30769.

[Playground link to code TS5.2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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-yOmHYkhs61QAAZOQBWVAAflQ9p8qBGYwm8jDEeGUYQMbjCeTacziTzM2AySNmWyuTyAiEIjERBWIGoYFCQJ2+ygRxOnDON0kYFIJUUUtnsK+NKZDDAnLhkqmnwaKRdYBwsE9MDlHeEonEyzIfbA4Wns6JoNdxR302BZyXDRX91qG6+W5fL49wyA93WPOUgA)

[Playground link to code TS3.3 where these errors do not appear](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#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-yOmHYkhs61QAAZOQBWVAAflQ9p8qBGYwm8jDEeGUYQMbjCeTacziTzM2AySNmWyuTyAiEIjERBWIGoYFCQJ2+ygRxOnDON0kYFIJUUUtnsK+NKZDDAnLhkqmnwaKRdYBwsE9MDlHeEonEyzIfbA4Wns6JoNdxR302BZyXDRX91qG6+W5fL49wyA93WPOUgA)

Comment: Is there any way to disallow `T` of being the union of the two types, and only be a specific instance?

Comment: No, there's an open feature request at [ms/TS#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) if you want to add your 

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks a lot for your help!